# Error; Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than

Tags: c#, gridview, tcp

```
foreach (TcpConnectionInformation info in tcpConnections)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value =info.LocalEndPoint.Address.ToString();
}
```

i am using this code for putting the value in gridview but this error is occurred.

> IndexOutOfRangeException - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

Parameter name: index

thanks
regards

Comment: Which index is out of range when you debug this?  The obvious guess is that your DataGridView has no rows, or its first row has fewer than two cells.

Comment: What event are you doing this on?   RowDataBound is a good place. The error you are getting must be from Rows[0] or Cells[1]. This could be because they dont yet exist, but it depends on which event you are adding this code.

Comment: is row[0] in a datagridview not the header row?

Comment: Also, why are you setting a static value with a loop like this?  Just use the last value in `tcpConnections`, since that's what it'll end up being anyway.  The loop is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: When the Exception is thrown, you can look into the inner exception to know which Array of your command throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The **index** parameter is referring to either the Rows[0] or the Cells[1]

Please check that you have at least one row in the dataGridView1 and that the first row has at least 2 cells.